# javascript html object model and template engine

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, template-engine

I am looking for javascript library which can do something like

```
var items = [1, 2];
var html = div(
    ul({
      id: "some-id",
      class: "some-class"
    })(items.each(function(item) {
      return li(item);
    }));
```

```
html == "<div><ul id='some-id' class='some-class'><li >1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>"
```

Comment: What the *hell* are you talking about? :)

Comment: I presume he wants some kind of templating engine written in JavaScript with syntax similar to the first segment to produce HTML similar to the second segment.

Comment: Do you want a templating engine?  It's hard to answer when we are not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I write it by myself. http://jshtmlbuilder.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Douglas Crockford's [supplant()](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html) method:

```
param = {domain: 'valvion.com', media: 'http://media.valvion.com/'};
url = "{media}logo.gif".supplant(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var $ul = $('<ul />',{
    "class":" some-class",
    "id": "some-id"
});
$.each(items,function(index,value) {
    $('<li />').text(value).appendTo($ul);
});
$ul.appendTo($('body'))
```

Although in this case, you can do it in pure javascript too:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.setAttribute('id',   'some-id');
    ul.setAttribute('class','some-class');
for(var i in items)
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = items[i];
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
document.body.appendChild(ul)
```

Answer (score 0):

John Resig has a great [template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) system.  The example he uses to illustrate its capability is exactly what you want to do.

You can use a script with the following syntax to create the output you want:

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
  <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=users[i].name%></a></li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

And feed it data with the following call in javascript:

```
var results = document.getElementById("results");
results.innerHTML = tmpl("item_tmpl", dataObject);
```